# How do I know when a file has been modified in a VBA Macro?

Tags: events, vba, ms-office, filesystemwatcher

Is there a way to watch a file in VBA (which is essentially VB6), so that I know when the file has been modified? -- similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205222/vba-watch-file-in-use) only I don't want to know when a file is *unused*, just when its *modified*.

The answers I've found have recommended using "FileSystemWatcher" and the Win32 API "FindFirstChangeNotification". I can't figure out how to use these though, any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I put together a solution that is able to detect file system changes, in VBA (VB6).

```
Public objWMIService, colMonitoredEvents, objEventObject

'call this every 1 second to check for changes'
Sub WatchCheck()
On Error GoTo timeout
    If objWMIService Is Nothing Then InitWatch 'one time init'
    Do While True
        Set objEventObject = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent(1) 
         '1 msec timeout if no events'
        MsgBox "got event"

        Select Case objEventObject.Path_.Class
            Case "__InstanceCreationEvent"
                MsgBox "A new file was just created: " & _
                    objEventObject.TargetInstance.PartComponent
            Case "__InstanceDeletionEvent"
                MsgBox "A file was just deleted: " & _
                    objEventObject.TargetInstance.PartComponent
            Case "__InstanceModificationEvent"
                MsgBox "A file was just modified: " & _
                    objEventObject.TargetInstance.PartComponent
        End Select
    Loop
Exit Sub
timeout:
    If Trim(Err.Source) = "SWbemEventSource" And Trim(Err.Description) = "Timed out" Then
        MsgBox "no events in the last 1 sec"
    Else
        MsgBox "ERROR watching"
    End If
End Sub
```

Copy and paste this sub near the above, it is called automatically if needed to initialize the global vars.

```
Sub InitWatch()
On Error GoTo initerr
    Dim watchSecs As Integer, watchPath As String
    watchSecs = 1 'look so many secs behind'
    watchPath = "c:\\\\scripts" 'look for changes in this dir'

    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
        ("SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN " & watchSecs & " WHERE " _
            & "Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and " _
                & "TargetInstance.GroupComponent= " _
                    & "'Win32_Directory.Name=""c:\\\\scripts""'")

    MsgBox "init done"
Exit Sub
initerr:
    MsgBox "ERROR during init - " & Err.Source & " -- " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a WMI temporary event consumer to watch the file, along the lines suggested [here](http://blogs.technet.com/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/04/04/how-can-i-monitor-for-different-types-of-events-with-just-one-script.aspx) but narrowing it down to a specific file instead of a folder

(This is assuming you can't just keep an eye on the file's Modified Date property..)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](http://www.mvps.org/vbvision/Sample_Projects.htm). The page has a "Watch Directory Demo" VB sample, by Bryan Stafford.

Answer (score 0):

I take it into vb6,run,display:ERROR watching.

Comment: Do you have the "scripts" directory under the C drive?