# Excel-VBA Find a pdf file given a path

Tags: excel, vba

**Problem:**
I need to know what files have been placed in a series of folders. I'd like to catalog which files are there in each folder and be able to do check this whenever I want without having to manually go into each folder. A sort of "syncing" of multiple files from different directories to a centralized catalog so that if I delete a file from a folder then the catalog will reflect the change.

I was hoping Excel could help with this. In short I want to be able to do this:

```
Filename     FilePath                     Exists

abc_4.23.11  C:\4-23-11\abc_4.23.11.pdf   *True/False*
```

**Details/Assumptions:**

The main directory won't change for a file. So File "abc.pdf" will always be in the same folder.

Let's assume Folder 1 has the following convention:

Folder Name: `mm-dd-yy (i.e 4-30-11)`

Contents of Folder 1: A series of other subfolders, we'll call these using letters so Folder A, Folder B, Folder C...Folder Z.

Inside each subfolder is a pdf file which I need to confirm that it is there.

Let me know if there's any questions.

Thanks a million!

Comment: Check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586169/how-do-i-know-when-a-file-has-been-modified-in-a-vba-macro) for some ideas.

Comment: I don't think Excel is going to help you much with this unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help to start with:

```
Sub ListAllFiles() 
Dim fs As FileSearch, ws As Worksheet, i As Long 
Set fs = Application.FileSearch 
With fs 
    .SearchSubFolders = False ' if you want to search the sub folders also, set to true
    .FileType = msoFileTypeAllFiles 'change this depending on the types of files you would like to filter
    .LookIn = "C:\"  'this will be the search location
    If .Execute > 0 Then 
        Set ws = Worksheets.Add 
        For i = 1 To .FoundFiles.Count 
            ws.Cells(i, 1) = .FoundFiles(i) 
        Next 
    Else 
        MsgBox "No files found" 
    End If 
End With 
End Sub
```

What you would need to do through is create the bit where it checks if the files still exists. Hope this helps