# Logging When Files Are Saved, Modified or Deleted Using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, wmi

I work with VBA in MS Access databases.  I'd like to be able to log when files are saved, modified or deleted without having to update the existing code to do the logging when the pertinent events take place.  I want the time, location and the name of the file.

I found a good example here: [when file modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586169/how-do-i-know-when-a-file-has-been-modified-in-a-vba-macro)

However, it only allows for monitoring a particular location (path).  I want to be able to log regardless of where the save, modify or delete takes place.  I'm only allowed to program in the MS Office environment in this situation.  It seems as though using the Windows API is going to be how this task will be achieved.  However, I don't have much experience working with the API.  Is there an easier way to achieve what I want that doesn't involve using the API?

Answer (score 0):

Have you worked with After_Updates or After_Insert macros? Also, is your application split? Meaning there's a front-end and a back-end of the database. You can create a separate table that mirrors that table that you need to track changes for. Every time a table is updates, run a macro that inserts a row to that table.

I'm assuming you're saving files to the database. If that's the case, add a after_update or after_insert macro that can keep track of when then files are being modified or added to the table.

Comment: He's talking about actual files in the file system. Not in tables.