# How to read text file in Excel VBA and keep updated

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to Excel VBA. I'm doing a project using Arduino and Gobetwino to log sensors data into a text file. To continue, I need to use a macro to log data from the text file to Excel and keep it updated every time I open it or run the macro. In addition, Gobetwino will write data in the text file line by line with date and content like the following:

```
11/28/2016 12:00:00 sensor triggered
11/29/2016 00:00:05 sensor triggered
11/29/2016 05:00:00 sensor triggered
```

I need to see the latest data in first line in Excel.

Can someone help me write VBA code for this?

Comment: Do you need to reload entire file just on start or on every new line? Reload entire file or just keep adding new lines to the spreadsheet?

Comment: For the keep updated part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586169/how-do-i-know-when-a-file-has-been-modified-in-a-vba-macro. This already have a solution out there :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick. You can assign it to a button or shortcut - it will refresh data from file in reverse upon each invocation.

```
Sub reverseFile()

    ' put the file into the same dir as spreasheet
    Const FILE_NAME = "sensorData.txt"

    Dim fileNum As Integer
    Dim line As String
    Dim c As New Collection
    Dim a() As String
    Dim i As Long

    ' read file line-by-line
    fileNum = FreeFile()
    Open ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator _
            & FILE_NAME For Input As #fileNum

    While Not EOF(fileNum)
        Line Input #fileNum, line
        c.Add line
    Wend

    Close #fileNum

    ' reverse the input lines into array
    ReDim a(1 To c.Count)
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a): a(i) = c(c.Count - i + 1): Next i

    ' display results in the spreadsheet
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").[a1]
        .CurrentRegion.Clear
        .Resize(UBound(a), 1) = Application.Transpose(a)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm also studying on VBA. Can you tell me which function here keep the data updated?

Comment: If you call this again, it will refresh the entire list from the file - i.e. it always reloads a full file. This can handle pretty large files quickly - you probably won't have issues with up to ~5-700000 records. But if you want to only load latest updates - remember the position in the file and use `Seek` command to read only changes.